# How to work with inheritance in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, inheritance, interface-builder

I just started to learn iOS programming and I have a problem with inheritance. There are 2 files.

First file

Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *myLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NewClass.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myLabel;
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myLabel.text = @"ViewController text!";    
    NewClass *myClass = [[[NewClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    [myClass setLabelText];
}
@end
```

Second file

Header:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface NewClass : ViewController 
-(void) setLabelText ;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "NewClass.h"
@implementation NewClass
- (void) setLabelText {
    myLabel.text = @"NewClass text!";
}
-(id)init { 
    self = [super init];                                       
    if (self != nil) {                                         
    }
    return self;                           
}
@end
```

And i set `myLabel` outlet in IB.

Why when i call `[myClass setLabelText];` nothing happens? There also remained "ViewController text!" on label view.
Where is my problem? How can i change `ViewController::myLabel.text` in `NewClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not inheritance that you are doing.  In your ViewController implementation, you have the following code

```
 NewClass *myClass = [[[NewClass alloc] init] autorelease];
[myClass setLabelText];
```

This is just creating an instance of the class NewClass and setting the labelText on that instance.  You are never displaying it or adding it to a view.

Comment: Even worse, because myClass is a subclass of ViewController, it will actually create it's own instance myClass when (or if) loaded... and round the loop the code goes. Voila - stack overflow error!

Answer (score 0):

This  example may help u where u can change label text by clicking on button.implement the below code in ur example

//class1.h

```
IBOutlet UILabel *text1;
```

@property(nonatomic,retain)UILabel *text1;

```
-(IBAction)press:(id)sender;
```

//class1.m

```
-(IBAction)press:(id)sender
```

{

```
Class2 *method = [[Class2 alloc]init];
NSString *string = [method sayhello];

[method release];
text1.text = string;
```

}

//class2.h

{

}

```
-(NSString *)sayhello;
```

@end

//class2.m

```
-(NSString *)sayhello
```

{

return @"hello";

}

connect button to file owner..

Answer (score 0):

```
NewClass *myClass = [[[NewClass alloc] init] autorelease];     
[myClass setLabelText];
```

Here you are creating the new view controller via alloc / init (not usual if you have a backing xib file for the view controller, you would usually use initWithNibName:) and then setting a property on an IBOutlet. At this point, the outlet will be `nil` since you haven't loaded a nib.

Also, as Nick Bull points out, you are just creating an instance, not displaying it anywhere. So even if you did use initWithNibName, you wouldn't see your changes unless you presented the view controller somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Wait... from the looks of it you are going to have some serious issues with stack overflows: when you load a ViewController, it in turn creates myClass. Because myClass is a subclass of ViewController, this in turn will create it's own variable 'myClass' when loaded... etc. This will continue forever, or until you get a stack overflow error.

In fact, I'm pretty confused by your code. Perhaps it might be time to rethink what you are trying to achieve and what your code should be doing?

Comment: You talking about 'self = [super init];' in NewClass?

Comment: @user1094316 no, I'm talking about  NewClass *myClass = [[[NewClass alloc] init] autorelease];   - because NewClass is a subclass of ViewController, when myClass loads it's going to run this line again. And again. And again... until your app crashes!

Comment: can you explain me how to fix it, please?

Comment: @user1094316 move "NewClass *myClass = [[[NewClass alloc] init] autorelease]; [myClass setLabelText];" to somewhere that's not a part of ViewController. Maybe in your appDelegate class. Potentially, you should be going back to some books before trying to do something like this - get the basics nailed first, and it'll solve any confusion!